# Django: Why does my Django model get "on_deleate" error

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I know that  ForeignHey of Django 2.2 require "on_delete" parameter and defined it in my model.
Nevertheless, I got the error "TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' "
Please tell  me the resolution of this error

I use Python3.7 and Django 2.2
My model is

```
from django.db import models
from treebeard.mp_tree import MP_Node
from django_model_to_dict.mixins import ToDictMixin

class Project(ToDictMixin,models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Task(MP_Node, ToDictMixin):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start=models.DateTimeField()
    end=models.DateTimeField()
    progress=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    custom_class=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True, blank=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        related_name="tasks",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and error is

```
File "/Users/gensan/python/basic3_7/lib/python3.7/site- packages/django_model_to_dict/models.py", line 127, in <module>
class Order(models.Model, ToDictMixin):
File "/Users/gensan/python/basic3_7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_model_to_dict/models.py", line 134, in Order
customer = models.ForeignKey(to=Customer, verbose_name=_('customer'), related_name='orders')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Thank you

Comment: This problem may be from different issues: You dont migrate your models and/or you did deleted your migrations files and django cannot make changes based on your new migrations file. Save your file and migrate, if migration is showing 'no migration detected' the issue might be with your db due to django not be able to make changes to it with your current migration files.

Comment: you are using django_model_to_dict module which doesnt support django 2.2. Either use different module or upgrade django_model_to_dict module models to support django 2.2

Comment: @EliasPrado thank for your advice.  Now, There is no migration file and this error occurs when I run "makemigration.py" at first

Comment: @Luqman, thanks and your point (django_model_to_dict module which doesnt support django 2.2) is right. But the same error occurs, despite deleting this module. I think that  other thing may pose this problem

Comment: @Luqman, I forgot to delate app of "django_model_to_dict" from INSTALLED_APP in settings.py. So I could solve this problem as delating it from there. Thank Luqman. On the other hand, I must seek different module...

Comment: @GenzoIto, this might be the issue. I had this problem as well. Try to rename your db to `db2.sqlite3` and see if the changes happen. But, you will lose your data.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the models.py that you defined Order class and not this file or maybe some other place of this file

Comment: This is the answer that I've consider the same way, but I've never defined Order class or Customer class. I presume the classes may come from django_model_to_dict model, but not sure of it